# Sample code for Xamarin Cross Platform bluetooth connection

Tags: xamarin.forms, xamarin.ios, bluetooth-lowenergy, core-bluetooth, ios-bluetooth

I have traied meny examples to connect Zebra IMZ320 Blutooth using Iphone on Xamarin Cross-Platform

I followed [CoreBluetooth Namespace](https://developer.xamarin.com/api/namespace/CoreBluetooth/)

[enter link description here](https://wojciechkulik.pl/xamarin-ios/how-to-communicate-with-bluetooth-low-energy-devices-on-ios)

and also using Plugin.BLE

but I couldnt connect my device eny one has success experience in connect Bluetooth printer using Xamarin cross platform ios

Comment: That's normal. From the documentation: "Secure Bluetooth 2.0" (https://www.zebra.com/content/dam/zebra/imz-series-mobile-printers-product-spec-sheet-en-us.pdf), it's not Bluetooth Low-Energy, it's "Classic Bluetooth", so you won't be able to find it with `CoreBluetooth.framework`. The whole "Peripheral/Service/Characteristic" doesn't exist in it.

Comment: Also, the printer page on Zebra (https://www.zebra.com/us/en/products/printers/mobile/mz-series.html) gives this document: https://www.zebra.com/content/dam/zebra/product-information/en-us/brochures-datasheets/software/ios-app-whitelisting-faq-en.pdf

Answer (score 3):

[`CoreBluetooth.framework`](https://developer.apple.com/documentation/corebluetooth) is for Bluetooth Low-Energy:

> Communicate with **Bluetooth 4.0 low-energy devices.**
>   The Core Bluetooth framework provides the classes needed for your apps
>   to communicate with devices that are equipped with **Bluetooth low
>   energy wireless technology**.

According to the specifications of the [Zebra IMZ320](https://www.zebra.com/content/dam/zebra/imz-series-mobile-printers-product-spec-sheet-en-us.pdf), the communication mode are:

> **Secure Bluetooth 2.0**, 802.11a/b/g/n (optional) or USB (client)
>   connectivity; Wi-Fi®-certified connectivity

That is not Bluetooth Low-Energy (which has been introduced in Bluetooth 4.0). You won't be able to find the printer with a Bluetooth Low-Energy scan, because the behavior, logic and implementation (protocols, norms, GATT, Peripheral/Service/Characteristic) are totally different.

Also, the [description page of the Zebra IMZ320](https://www.zebra.com/us/en/products/printers/mobile/mz-series.html) gives a link ([FAQ - Creating & Registering An IOS App](https://www.zebra.com/content/dam/zebra/product-information/en-us/brochures-datasheets/software/ios-app-whitelisting-faq-en.pdf)) to how develop apps for it.
You need to use [ExternalAccessory.framework](https://developer.apple.com/documentation/externalaccessory) for it.

> If your app communicates with a Zebra product via Bluetooth using the
>   External Accessory Framework, and you plan to distribute the app via
>   the App Store or Volume Purchase Program Store, then you must register
>   the app with Zebra.

This page is general (and not specific to that printer). But according to the specs, it's not Bluetooth Low-Energy compliant (while others products might be, that's why there is a paragraph talking about CoreBluetooth in it).

That's normal behavior (using `ExternalAccessory` vs `CoreBluetooth` framework), because each one of them has a specific meaning and use.

**Conclusion:**

Use ExternalAccessory.framework, it is also [available on Xamarin](https://developer.xamarin.com/api/namespace/ExternalAccessory/).